# Return Value Try catch?

Tags: java, android, try-catch

I try to do set Text in onBindViewHolder, I'm sure that I create it with no mistake, because if I set dummy data setText, it does setText to recycler view.

[image: Trying on try catch but don't do any set text]

But if I create try catch, it doesn't change anything.
Help me.

```
try {
            Transaksi transaksi = arrayTransaksi.get(position);
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            Date date1=new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse(transaksi.getTanggal_transaksi());
            long milis = date1.getTime();
            if (milis == calendar.get(Calendar.DATE)){
                holder.textHariTransaksi.setText("Today");
                holder.textTanggal.setText(transaksi.getTanggal_transaksi());
                holder.textHarga.setText(String.valueOf(transaksi.getHarga_transaksi()));
            }else if(calendar.get(Calendar.DATE) - milis == 1){
                holder.textHariTransaksi.setText("Yesterday");
                holder.textTanggal.setText(transaksi.getTanggal_transaksi());
                holder.textHarga.setText(String.valueOf(transaksi.getHarga_transaksi()));
            }else{
                SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("l");
                holder.textHariTransaksi.setText(dateFormat.format(date1));
                holder.textTanggal.setText(transaksi.getTanggal_transaksi());
                holder.textHarga.setText(String.valueOf(transaksi.getHarga_transaksi()));
            }

        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

if im not using try catch, it say " error: unreported exception ParseException; must be caught or declared to be thrown "

Comment: Please add code as text, not image.

Comment: Either remove the try catch and check the log where it crashes or check the stacktrace for exceptions and post it here.

Comment: yes, im sorry. i just add some code..

Comment: if i remove the try catch, it will create some error " error: unreported exception ParseException; must be caught or declared to be thrown "

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this)

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to setText you have to access the function from a UI thread, in order to do that you have to call runOnUiThread function.

```
Activity.runOnUiThread(() =>{ call setText here })
```

I'm using a mobile right now, that's why my answer is brief.

Edit:
Also check if all the data you're trying to set as text is an actual string.